# Can I force a higher TCP segment size with netcat?

Tags: ipv4, tcp, linux, fragmentation

I'm using netcat to send random data from A to B, both Linux machines on Ethernet networks, with a router in the middle. For pedagogic purposes I'd like to force IP fragmentation on the router (Cisco 1811, base image). I've first lowered the MTU to 500 (instead of the original 1500) on the outbound router interface, but then the router sends and ICMP `fragmentation needed` message and A lowers TCP segment size accordingly. I've then set a lower MTU directly on B, but then B advertises a lower Maximum Segment Size and A accepts it, leading to no fragmentation.

Can I make A ignore B's MSS in the negociation and use a 1500-tailored segment size anyway? Or do you see another way to force IP fragmentation on the router?

For practical reasons I cannot recompile the kernel or install arbitrary software on the machines, I have to work with what's there (reasonably standard set of networking tools I hope).

Comment: If you are getting that message, then the `df` bit is set, and nothing you do will cause fragmentation.

Comment: Right. It is set when I limit the MTU directly on the router (and yet the router fragments, but it is marginal -- I'm bothered by the sender adapting segment size). Can I force this bit to 0 then?

Comment: Aaargh, it looks like `ping -s 1500 -M dont X.X.X.X` would be perfect for what I need, but it requires iputils-ping and I don't have it on the machines...

Comment: It sounds like you are venturing into host/OS territory, which is off-topic here. As far as I can tell, netcat doesn't have an option to not set the `df` bit. On Cisco devices, you can simply set the size of the ping packets. We do that to test circuits by pinging with _very_ oversized packets for a long time. If all the packet fragments can be reassembled (no fragments are lost), then that is a good sign.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Sorry, I had added my answer with this intent, but never accepted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the following configuration:

- Standard MTU on A and B;
- MTU lowered to 500 on the router (B side);
- `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_no_pmtu_disc` set to 1 on the sender (A).

And then the sender sticks to 1500 byte segments, and the router fragments.